# Does Flutter Streambuilder use cache on setState or retrieve all documents again from the firestore database?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a chat functionality for my Flutter application.

To ensure that the latest message of a user is always showed, I need the real-time functionality of a Streambuilder.

However, I need to introduce pagination as well to avoid that all chat messages from the database are loaded from the database each time the Widget is rebuilt.

I've implemented this behaviour successfully with the code below. Each time the maximum scrollExtent is reached, the Widget is rebuilt with a higher documentLimit.

My question is now the following:

**When setState is called, will the data from the streambuilder that was already there be read again from the database? Or will the Streambuilder use its cache where possible and only use reads for the documents that it does not have?**

In other words, with a documentLimit of 20, will each set state only cost me maximum 20 extra reads? Or will it cost me the entire new documentLimit?

```
void initState() {
    maxMessageToDisplay = 20;
    _scrollController = ScrollController();
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels == _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        setState(() {
          maxMessageToDisplay += 20;
        });
      }
    });
    super.initState();
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _firestore.collection('chat').limit(maxMessageToDisplay).orderBy('timestamp', descending: true).snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
     
        final messages = snapshot.data.documents;

        messages.sort((a, b) => b.data['timestamp'].compareTo(a.data['timestamp']));
        var format = new DateFormat("Hm");

        List<MessageBubble> messageBubbles = [];
        for (var message in messages) {
          final messageText = message.data['text'];
          final messageSender = message.data['sender'];
          final messagePhoto = message.data['photo'];
          final messageUserId = message.data['uid'];

          final messageTime = format.format(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(message.data['timestamp'], isUtc: false));    

          final messageBubble = MessageBubble(
            sender: messageSender,
            text: messageText,
            photo: messagePhoto,
            time: messageTime,
            userId: messageUserId,
          );
          messageBubbles.add(messageBubble);
        }
        return Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            controller: _scrollController,
            reverse: true,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
            children: messageBubbles,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By changing the `limit` you create a whole new query and `all` data for it is loaded as it is for each new query.

To avoid loading all data you could implement a pagination as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors). Where you would use the last loaded `doc` and `startAfter` to load the next 20 elements from the point where the previous query stoped. It would make your code more complicated to handle multiple realtime queries and keep track of the last `docs`.

You could also consider to have only the last 20 messages in realtime and if you need the older ones to get them with the `get` call only once because they would probably not change. Make sure to store all messages from the listener and `get` calls into a single `List` and make sure not to store duplicates accidentaly.

I would also consider if it is so importand to avoid loading all data when watching older messages. Does that happen so often in your app? I have multiple chat apps with Firebase that use the same logic with just increasing the `limit`. Users very rarely watch older messages so implementing such workflows with pagination would not have much effect on the billing and total read amount.

Comment: Hi Tarik, thanks for your response! I'm going to try your suggestion of splitting it up in a realtime streambuilder and a paginated get call (losing the realtime) for older messages! Thanks a lot for the insights!